# conversion of .tif to .text using tesseract

Tags: python, text, tiff, tesseract

I have a pdf file with more than 60+ pages.
I have split each page in different pdf using pyPdf.  Now, each pdf have some data tables in it.
Then I convert those pdf to .tif
I want to convert that data tables from .tif to text using tesseract or tesseract-ocr.
I tried the things but not worked.

Can anyone have any idea about the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "not worked". DO you have problems making tesseract working? Do you have bad quality result with the ocr? ...

Comment: its solved. following link help me in it. thanks. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=882899